# Upper bound to sum of squares using given sum

Tags: summation, cauchy-schwarz-inequality, sums-of-squares

If $\sum_{i = 1}^n a_i = x$ for $a_i \geq 0$, then is it possible to find upper bound to $\sum_{i=1}^n a_i^2$?
I know that the lower bound can be easily determined using *Cauchy- Schwarz Inequality*. But how to derive the upper bound?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. If you want to type in italic, enclose your text between a pair of asterisks.

Answer (score 1):

One simple bound is $$\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i^2 \leq \sum_{i=1}^{n}\sum_{j=1}^{n}a_ia_j = \left(\sum_{i=1}^{n} a_i\right) \left(\sum_{j=1}^{n} a_j\right) = x^2.$$
The inequality holds because the LHS is the sum of just the $i=j$ terms in the double sum.

This bound is achieved if and only if $a_i a_j = 0$ whenever $i \neq j$, which is true if and only if at most one of the $a_i$'s is nonzero.

Answer (score 0):

Do you assume that $a_i\ge 0$  ?

Otherwise take $a_1+a_2=0$ with $a_1=t$, $a_2=-t$, then $a_1^2+a_2^2=2t^2$ has no upper bound.

Comment: Yes $a_i \geq 0$

Answer (score 0):

If you also know an upper bound on the $a_i \ge 0$. Then you also have:
$$ \sum_{i=1}^n a_i^2 \le \max_i a_i \cdot \sum_{i=1}^n a_i = x \cdot \max_i a_i $$